# Use kotlin DSL from a separate file

Tags: kotlin, plugins, dsl

I'm trying to write a maven plugin with kotlin DSL that creates a configuration object. The plugin will depend on that configuration during its operation.

I think I need to use the DSL like following: in runtime load a separate file with kotlin script, execute it and assign result to a variable in the plugin code.

Is there any good way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out there is a simple answer:
https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/examples/kotlin-jsr223-local-example/